# Bundling CSS and Scripts in Web Forms application

Tags: c#, webforms, bundle

I am here on a pickle about bundling my CSS and Scripts to my Web Forms application.

First of all, I'd like to point out that I was following this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx

I have already in the App_Start the class BundleConfig that looks like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace SitePessoal.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery/core/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery/core/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/CSS/css").Include(
                        "~/CSS/Estilos.css", 
                        "~/CSS/Print.css", 
                        "~/CSS/Styles.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have downloaded the Optimization package with Nugget, so afterwards I went to my Global.asax file and tried to register this in the Application_Start method like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup  
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is where things do not work. Unfortunately, it keeps underlining the class with red and giving me the following messages:

```
Error   3   The name 'BundleTable' does not exist in the current context
Error   4   The name 'BundleTable' does not exist in the current context
Error   2   The name 'BundleConfig' does not exist in the current context
```

Any ideas as to why this may be happening? Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Mad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem @MadGatsu encountered following the same tutorial.

@Pricey is correct, and %MadGatsu correctly adds references to the **Global.asax**, including,

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<script RunAt="server">        
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

But there is a little more to it.

I deduce, based on the lack of **Global.asax.cs**, that we have *Websites*. In this case, we need to put our **Bundleconfig.cs** file in the special aspnet folder, **App_Code**.  Do not add a **App_Start** folder to contain the file because it will not work.  Simply moving my **BundleConfig.cs** to **App_Code** from **App_Start** corrected the *'BundleConfig' does not exist in the current context* error.

Comment: Will try that solution and I will answer soon. Cheers! :)

Comment: Indeed your solution fixed the issue with the error message I was getting about "BundleConfig" not existing in the current context! Marked as solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably fixed this already but just in case it's of use to anyone.. you probably need to add a reference to `System.Web.Optimization` and your `BundleConfig` class namespace `SitePessoal.Web` to your `Global.asax.cs`

Example:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
using SitePessoal.Web;

namespace SitePessoal.Web.Application
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
              BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You probably also need to add the `System.Web.Optimization` namespace to your pages in your `web.config` if you haven't done it already, because it is not enough just to add the reference to the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` package via `NuGet`.

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Hi Pricey, thanks for giving a possible answer. In fact, this topic was still open because I did not solve it at all yet. I will try your solution and give feedback as soon as possible (aka tomorrow!). Many thanks regardless of the result.

Comment: Hi Pricey, I haven't got time to test this out until now. Very busy at work. I tried your solution, but it still does not work. I have a Web Site, not Web application, so I do not have a Globa.asax.cs class file. Instead, I added to the Global.asax this:

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SitePessoal.Web" %>

But it shows me error that BundleConfig does not exist in this context. In web.config file everything is fine and the System.Optimization is already there. Any more ideas? Thanks @Pricey.